# 'The server identity of ttotaliampleton.com could not be verified.' Why is that?

Tags: iphone, certificate

[image]

This pop-message just comes out of nowhere. How can i fix this? Is it a bug?

Comment: What do you mean with "out of nowhere"? This looks like a certificate from System Settings, not a pop-up message. The certificate has expired though.

Comment: @nohillside yes it's like a certficate to verify the SSL? I got this from a friend of mine and we both not sure why it happens

Comment: The question is unclear right now. You mention a pop-up but the screenshot shows something else. Where does the screenshot come from? What did you do on the phone before the pop-up was shown? How did you get from the pop-up to the screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Before this screenshot is shown, a pop-up message shows cannot verify server identity

Comment: What exactly were you doing before you got the message - so that we can try to do the same thing on our machines to reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this message because something on your phone (maybe your browser, or an app) was tryping to access https://ttotaliampleton.club/. The SSL certificate of the site has expired end of July so iOS can't verify the identity of the server/site.

Comment: thank you, I get it now